# Stick Footer at the Bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to make the footer position at the bottom of the page. My code for footer is...

```css
footer{
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(93, 158, 255);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <h5>Copyrigth &copy;
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
        </script>
      </h5>
      <h5>Designed by:  - Junior Web Development</h5>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is [index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Ypd.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "relative footer"? Maybe fixed?

Comment: add position: fixed, i think you want to achive that your footer should be sticked always to the bottom of the screen

Comment: i want position: relative...page has e.x height:1000px then footer is bottom

Comment: You want to place footer at the bottom of page?

Comment: yes...at the bottom

Comment: Then you gotta position it as "fixed". There's no way to position it at bottom with "relative" positioning. Do it like, `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you.

```
footer{
    height: 120px;
    background-color: rgb(93, 158, 255);
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot the dot in css class `.footer`, and you should use `position: absolute;`

here a working example, useful info about [Css Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <h5>Copyrigth &copy;
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
    </script>
    </h5>
    <div>
        <h5>Designed by:  - Junior Web Development</h5>
    </div> 
    </div>
```